# Centos8 java application as service

Tags: linux, java, service, centos8, springboot

**Background:**

We are running java springboot applications on Centos8 (for now...) as service but applications take some time to startup: flyway, DAO initialization... Actualy start of service can take about 7 minuts

**SystemD service**

```
[Unit]
Description=SSO
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=my_app
Group=my_app

SuccessExitStatus=143

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "exec /home/my_app/sso/run.sh start >&1"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "exec /home/my_app/sso/run.sh stop >&1"
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c "exec /home/my_app/sso/run.sh restart >&1"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Application start script**

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_DIR=/home/my_app/sso/
LOG_PATH=$BASE_DIR/logs/
PID_FILE=$BASE_DIR/app.pid

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
... and tons of another JAVA_OPTS ...

START_COMMAND="java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $BASE_DIR/deploy/sso.jar"

start() {
  PID=`$START_COMMAND >> $LOG_PATH/sso-${HOSTNAME}.log & echo $!`
}

case "$1" in
start)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
            start
        else
            echo "Already running [$PID]"
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        start
    fi

    if [ -z $PID ]; then
        echo "Failed starting"
        exit 1
    else
        echo $PID > $PID_FILE
        echo "Started [$PID]"
        exit 0
    fi
;;

status)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
            echo "Not running (process dead but PID file exists)"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Running [$PID]"
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
        exit 0
    fi
;;
stop)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
            echo "Not running (process dead but PID file exists)"
            rm -f $PID_FILE
            exit 1
        else
            PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
            kill -term $PID
            echo "Stopped [$PID]"
            rm -f $PID_FILE
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running (PID not found)"
        exit 0
    fi
;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
    exit 0
esac
```

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to monitor starting java application to see in which state currently is (loading, started, restarting, stale...)?
2. Any hints for above service/start scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a separate bash script? You can put all that stuff directly in the systemd unit and it will be a lot cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: Hi there Michael. Server which is application running on is in client's datacenter and we do not have root access so any changes in service are made by someone else and those changes can take even 14 days ... :(